# UPDATE ON SAME COLUMN ON MULTIPLE ROWS WITH DIFFERENT VALUES

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is an example. TABLE 1 is manually created where the first three columns are loaded here from an external file. Fourth column(SHOWROOM_ID) will be taken from TABLE2 and the rest of the columns in TABLE 1 will be updated based on criteria.

**TABLE 1**

```
NAME     |OLD_CPR_NO |OLD_COS_NO |SHOWROOM_ID|NM_CPR_COS_MAT|NM_CPR_MAT|COS_CPR_MAT|
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FORD     | 45        | 487       |           |              |          |    
TOYOTA   | 78        | 562       |           |              |          |
BENZ     | 55        | 789       |           |              |          |
JEEP     | 66        | 124       |           |              |          |
HONDA    | 34        | 142       |           |              |          |
KIA      | 12        | 962       |           |              |          |
GM       | 89        | 7787      |           |              |          |
CHRYSLER | 45        | 236       |           |              |          |
AUDI     | 67        | 4789      |           |              |          |
```

**TABLE 2**

```
PK|NAME     |OLD_CPR_NO |OLD_COS_NO |SHOWROOM_ID
---------------------------------------------
1  |FORD     | 45        | 487       |   1    
2  |TOYOTA   | 78        | 562       |   2   
3  |CIAT     | 55        | 789       |   3     
4  |JEEP     | 66        | 124       |   5    
5  |HONDA    | 34        | 456       |   6   
6  |MUSTANG  | 12        | 962       |   7   
7  |GM       | 89        | 56        |   8   
8  |CHRYSLER | 45        | 236       |   9   
9  |AUDI     | 67        | 4789      |   10
```

**STEP 1:** `Update NM_CPR_COS_MAT column from table 1`. This is an indicator field where `NAME,OLD_CPR_NO,OLD_COS_NO` matches from TABLE 1 and TABLE 2 then assign indicator 'Y'

I was able to attain the results based on my below query:

```
UPDATE TABLE_1 TAB1
SET NM_CPR_COS_MAT = (SELECT 'Y'
FROM 
TABLE_2 TAB2
WHERE
TRIM(TAB1.NAME) = TRIM(TAB2.NAME)
AND TRIM(TAB1.OLD_CPR_NO) = TRIM(TAB2.OLD_CPR_NO)
AND TRIM(TAB1.OLD_COS_NO) = TRIM(TAB2.OLD_COS_NO)
;
COMMIT;

UPDATE TABLE_1 TAB1
SET SHOWROOM_ID= (SELECT TAB2.SHOWROOM_ID
FROM 
TABLE_2 TAB2
WHERE
TRIM(TAB1.NAME) = TRIM(TAB2.NAME)
AND TRIM(TAB1.OLD_CPR_NO) = TRIM(TAB2.OLD_CPR_NO)
AND TRIM(TAB1.OLD_COS_NO) = TRIM(TAB2.OLD_COS_NO)
AND TRIM(TAB1.NM_CPR_COS_MAT) = 'Y'
;
COMMIT;
```

**RESULT:**

```
TABLE 1
NAME     |OLD_CPR_NO |OLD_COS_NO |SHOWROOM_ID|NM_CPR_COS_MAT|NM_CPR_MAT|COS_CPR_MAT|
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FORD     | 45        | 487       |      1    |       Y      |          |    
TOYOTA   | 78        | 562       |      2    |       Y      |          |
BENZ     | 55        | 789       |           |              |          |
JEEP     | 66        | 124       |      5    |       Y      |          |
HONDA    | 34        | 142       |           |              |          |
KIA      | 12        | 962       |           |              |          |
GM       | 89        | 7787      |           |              |          |
CHRYSLER | 45        | 236       |     9     |       Y      |          |
AUDI     | 67        | 4789      |     10    |      Y       |          |
```

From the below resulting table, I have to again `UPDATE SHOWROOM_ID column` and `NM_CPR_MAT`

```
TABLE 1
NAME     |OLD_CPR_NO |OLD_COS_NO |SHOWROOM_ID|NM_CPR_COS_MAT|NM_CPR_MAT|COS_CPR_MAT|
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FORD     | 45        | 487       |      1    |       Y      |          |    
TOYOTA   | 78        | 562       |      2    |       Y      |          |
BENZ     | 55        | 789       |           |              |          |
JEEP     | 66        | 124       |      5    |       Y      |          |
HONDA    | 34        | 142       |           |              |          |
KIA      | 12        | 962       |           |              |          |
GM       | 89        | 7787      |           |              |          |
CHRYSLER | 45        | 236       |     9     |       Y      |          |
AUDI     | 67        | 4789      |     10    |      Y       |          |

STEP 2:
UPDATE TABLE_1 TAB1
SET NM_CPR_MAT = (SELECT 'Y'
FROM 
TABLE_2 TAB2
WHERE
TRIM(TAB1.NAME) = TRIM(TAB2.NAME)
AND TRIM(TAB1.OLD_CPR_NO) = TRIM(TAB2.OLD_CPR_NO)
AND TRIM(NM_CPR_COS_MAT) IS NULL
;
COMMIT;

UPDATE TABLE_1 TAB1
SET SHOWROOM_ID= (SELECT TAB2.SHOWROOM_ID
FROM 
TABLE_2 TAB2
WHERE
WHERE
TRIM(TAB1.NAME) = TRIM(TAB2.NAME)
AND TRIM(TAB1.OLD_CPR_NO) = TRIM(TAB2.OLD_CPR_NO)
AND TRIM(NM_CPR_COS_MAT) IS NULL
AND TRIM(NM_CPR_MAT) = 'Y'
;
COMMIT;
```

I AM GETTING THE BELOW RESULTS.I AM GETTING THE CORRECT 'Y' IN `NM_CPR_MAT` COLUMNS AND ALSO THE CORRECT NUMBERS IN `SHOWROOM_ID` FOR THE NEW UPDATE STATEMENT BUT THE NUMBERS THAT WAS UPDATED IN THE **PREVIOUS UPDATED STATEMENT WERE GONE.**

```
TABLE 1
NAME     |OLD_CPR_NO |OLD_COS_NO |SHOWROOM_ID|NM_CPR_COS_MAT|NM_CPR_MAT|COS_CPR_MAT|
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FORD     | 45        | 487       |           |       Y      |          |    
TOYOTA   | 78        | 562       |           |       Y      |          |
BENZ     | 55        | 789       |           |              |          |
JEEP     | 66        | 124       |           |       Y      |          |
HONDA    | 34        | 142       |      6    |              |    Y     |
KIA      | 12        | 962       |           |              |          |
GM       | 89        | 7787      |      8    |              |    Y     |
CHRYSLER | 45        | 236       |           |      Y       |          |
AUDI     | 67        | 4789      |           |      Y       |          |
```

Comment: And spend some time learning how to format your posts on this web site. If you are in a hurry, that's your problem; you shouldn't post here when you are in a hurry.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty hard to be sure when you have posted malformed SQL but it seems both queries update the whole table. Where the subquery conditions don't match anything in `tab2` the update will assign null. So the second query overwrites the results of the first.

You can easily fix this by adding a WHERE condition to the second update statement:

```
where SHOWROOM_ID is null
```